# disabling cookies doesn't work

Tags: php, session-cookies

I tried this:

```
 ini_set("session.use_cookies", 0);
 ini_set("session.use_only_cookies", 0);
 ini_set("session.use_trans_sid", 1);
 ini_set("session.cache_limiter", "");
```

but according to firefox my site still creates cookies.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Are you talking about your session cookie? Or cookies in general?

Comment: I am talking about my PHPSESSION cookie

Comment: Try to add this into .htaccess: `session.use_cookies = 0`